# New code coverage in Corbertura

Tags: java, code-coverage

How does it track whether new code has

> X%+

coverage?

If one edits an old class, are the untouched lines counted in terms of coverage? Or does it just count new classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm from [Codecov](https://codecov.io) and have a solution that helps you here. We call this the "Coverage Diff" it's a metrics that only concerns lines adjusted in a commit/pull.

I'm not aware of any other solution for Java that shows off the Coverage Diff. Perhaps you can give Codecov a shot: https://github.com/codecov/example-java

Thanks!